# Mapping list of dict objects to a new list of dict objects

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dict objects, like:

```
>>> j = [{ "field": "dev_name", "value": ['dev_1', 'dev_2', 'dev_3']}, { "field": "dev_type", "value": ['p2p', 'Radwin', 'Talsima']}]
```

I want to create a new list of dict items, from above, like this:

```
>>> k = [{ "dev_name": ['dev_1', 'dev_2', 'dev_3']}, { "dev_type": ['p2p', 'Radwin', 'Talsima']}]
```

Where `keys` in k are `values` in j.

Can someone help me ?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why do you want the second one to be a list of dicts instead of just one big dict?

Answer (score 3):

You can't really do key lookup on a list of dicts. Instead, I propose just making one big dict. Then you can do `k['dev_name']` and get the list of device names instead of having to awkwardly iterate through a list of dicts looking for the one with the key you want:

```
k = {d['field']: d['value'] for d in j}
```

If you really need a list of dicts, you can instead do

```
k = [{d['field']: d['value']} for d in j]
```